# Perl Test::MockTime + Time::localtime

Tags: perl, time

I'm trying to replace current time with Test::MockTime module. It works fine:

```
use Test::MockTime qw(:all);
use Time::Local;
my $sec  = 0;
my $min  = 0;
my $hour = 14;
my $mday = 1; #1-31
my $mon  = 1; #1-12
my $year = 2013; #1970-...
set_fixed_time(timelocal($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon-1,$year-1900));
print join "\n", localtime;
```

But, when I use Time::localtime, nothing happens:

```
use Time::localtime;
use Time::Local;
use Test::MockTime qw(:all);

my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year)=(0,0,14,1,1,2013);

set_fixed_time(timelocal($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon-1,$year-1900));

my $t=localtime();
my $xmon=$t->mon;
my $xyear=$t->year;
my $xday=$t->mday;
my $xmon_now=$xmon+1;
my $xyear_now=$xyear+1900;

print "$xmon_now $xyear_now\n";
```

The output will be "12 2012"
How can I change time in my tests when Time::localtime is used?
Thanks and sorry for my English

UPD:

```
use Time::localtime;
use Test::MockTime qw(:all);
```

didnt work

```
use Test::MockTime qw(:all);
use Time::localtime;
```

works fine) perl magic

Comment: (You should have made your update an answer, and accepted that!)

Comment: can't accept it. dont understand why it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test::MockTime overrides `localtime`, but `Time::localtime` uses `CORE::localtime` (the unoverrided version of `localtime`). You'd have to rewrite Time::localtime's `localtime`.